# elasticsearch: Cannot find indexed data (unit Node is closed)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to start using elasticsearch (having been a long-term compass user) and I'm having some pretty serious problems with the basics, which is highly frustrating.

The current problem I'm facing is that indexed data is not showing up until after the node is closed. Here is a sample of my code

```
Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
Client client = node.client();

client.prepareIndex("index1", "type1", "1").setSource("{ \"name\": \"Aaron\"}").execute().actionGet();
client.prepareIndex("index1", "type1", "2").setSource("{ \"name\": \"Andrew\"}").execute().actionGet();
client.prepareIndex("index1", "type1", "3").setSource("{ \"name\": \"Alistair\"}").execute().actionGet();

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("name", "a*");
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("index1");
searchRequestBuilder.setTypes("type1");
searchRequestBuilder.setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT);
searchRequestBuilder.setQuery(queryBuilder);

SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
System.out.println("Response contains " + response.getHits().totalHits() + " hits");
for (SearchHit currentHit : response.getHits())
{
    System.out.println(currentHit.getSourceAsString());
}

client.close();
node.close();
```

The first time I run this, it finds no hits in the search. However, if I run it again - it does indeed find the names that all begin with the letter "A" (don't get me started on the auto-lowercasing of indexed items, but not of searches - that cost me over an hour).

If I remover the close, it doesn't matter how many times I run the above I never find results. However, if I add the close statements, it works second time (every time).

It feels like something to do with having buffered index changes that aren't flushed?

I am sure I am missing something obvious and basic. But I just cannot put my finger on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to [refresh](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) the index before you'll be able to search for the latest changes. Put this after the indexing, before executing the search:

```
client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh("index1").execute().actionGet();
```

With the default settings, Elasticsearch will call `refresh` periodically every 1 second.